# Send input to background process

Tags: background-process

I have a process that i run with this command:

`java -jar loginserver.jar &`

I need to be able to send commands to this program.  I've tried bg/fg but apparently it doesn't persist thru sessions.  Is there any other way I can do this?

Comment: What type of input do you need to send?

Comment: Just text.  Commands like 'shutdown 10' where 10 is the number of minutes before it shuts down.. etc.  I've also tried echo "shutdown 10" > /procs/pid/fd/0 with no success.  The bg/fg works but only in the same ssh session.

Comment: Are the only commands that you're trying to send shutdown or restart commands? Are you trying to run this as a daemon rather than just a process within your shell session?

Comment: This is a loginserver.  I can send commands to shutdown worlds for a game I'm hosting.  The commands are interpreted by the loginserver, so they can really be whatever.  Shutdown was just an example.

Answer (score -1):

Try screen (http://linux.die.net/man/1/screen).